# Mascara de CPF e Data de Nascimento Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: 
Criei um CRUD simples e estou querendo usar mascara nos campos data de nascimento, CPF e telefone.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do função `create` do CRUD:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Bdfinal
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Bdfinal</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sobrenome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sobrenome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sobrenome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telefone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sexo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sexo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sexo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar uma biblioteca de máscaras em `jQuery` criada pelo brasileiro Igor Escobar. É possível criar praticamente qualquer tipo de máscara com a biblioteca.

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

### Documentação

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html

### 1. Baixando e adicionando o plugin no seu projeto

No link informado acima, você encontra um link para download da biblioteca. Após baixá-lo, adicione o mesmo no seu projeto. Para isso, dentro do **wwwroot** do seu projeto, crie uma pasta chamada **lib** (caso não exista) e dentro dela coloque a pasta que acabou de baixar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 2. Referenciando a biblioteca

Após adicionar a biblioteca no projeto, temos que referenciá-la para podemos usá-la posteriormente. Dentro do arquivo de layout do seu site ou na página que deseja utilizar a máscara, dentro da tag `<body>` e quase no *closing* da mesma, adicione a seguinte linha:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-mask-plugin/src/jquery.mask.js" type="text/javascript" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

### 3. Utilizando

Em um campo de CPF por exemplo, vai ficar da seguinte maneira.

Código html:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
     <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
          <label>CPF</label>
          <input id="txtCPF" asp-for="CPF" class="form-control" style="height: 39px" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

Na área de scripts da sua página:

```
$('#txtCPF').mask('000.000.000-00', { placeholder: "___.___.___-__" });
```

No link de documentação informado, você confere todas as máscaras possíveis.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar mascaras é sempre um bom pois facilita o preenchimento do formulario e auxilia o usuário no preenchimento correto dos dados. Normalmente mascaras são aplicadas via javascripts, pois a execução direto no brower deixa mais rapido a resposta, sem necessitar de envio para o servidor de dados.

O Jquery é um boa alternativa

**Telefone**

```
  jQuery("input.telefone")
            .mask("(99) 9999-9999?9")
            .focusout(function (event) {  
                var target, phone, element;  
                target = (event.currentTarget) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;  
                phone = target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
                element = $(target);  
                element.unmask();  
                if(phone.length > 10) {  
                    element.mask("(99) 99999-999?9");  
                } else {  
                    element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");  
                }  
            });
```

Adicionar o plugin:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

**Cpf**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var $seuCampoCpf = $("#CPF");
        $seuCampoCpf.mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
    });
</script>
```

Adicione tambem o plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

**Data de Nascimento**

```
$("#campoData").mask("99/99/9999");
```

Fonte: http://vinteum.com/jquery-mask-mascaras-para-campos-html-utilizando-jquery/